# Make change program GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jtextfield

I wrote a program a few weeks ago in order to make change, now I am trying to turn that program into a gui and having a bit of an issue. I can make the gui and make the gui look pretty using the Netbeans Jframe editor which makes it simple my issue is trying to figure out how to plug in my code. I plugged my program into the first Jbutton, but cannot figure out how to get the user input from the gui rather then the program. I click the Jbutton and it asks the console to do the work rather than the gui. Please help.

**what my gui looks like**

[image]

**Original code**

```
public static void main (String[] Args) {

    // Initialize varriables
    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickles = 5;
    int pennies = 1;

    //Loop starts here
    while(true) {

    System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");

    // Blank Output for spacing
    System.out.println();
    // User Input "remember this for reference"
    Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);


   int input = Userinput.nextInt();


   //while loop end
   if(input<1) {
    break;  //break is a keyword that exits the loop when a condition is met.
   }

   int q = input/quarters;
   input -= q*quarters;
   String A = "Quarters:" +q;

    //Blank Output for spacing
    System.out.println();


   //output quarters
   System.out.println(A);


   int d = input/dimes;
   input -= d*dimes;
   String B = "Dimes:" +d;

   //output dimes
   System.out.println(B);


   int n = input/nickles;
   input -= n*nickles;
   String C = "Nickles:" +n;

   //output nickles
   System.out.println(C);


   int p = input/pennies;
   input -= p*pennies;
   String D = "Pennies:" +p;

   //output pennies
   System.out.println(D);




  } 





   }
```

**Current Code with GUI using Netbeans Jframe Editor**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Christ
 */
public class coin extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public coin() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Enter a Number (1-99)");

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Quarters");

    jLabel3.setText("Dimes");

    jLabel4.setText("Nickles");

    jLabel5.setText("Pennies");

    jButton1.setText("Calculate");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Clear");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
                     .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,        179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(55, 55, 55)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 53, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    // Initialize varriables
    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickles = 5;
    int pennies = 1;

    //Loop starts here
    while(true) {

    System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");

    // Blank Output for spacing
    System.out.println();
    // User Input "remember this for reference"
    Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);


   int input = Userinput.nextInt();


   //while loop end
   if(input<1) {
    break;  //break is a keyword that exits the loop when a condition is met.
   }

   int q = input/quarters;
   input -= q*quarters;
   String A = "Quarters:" +q;

    //Blank Output for spacing
    System.out.println();


   //output quarters
   System.out.println(A);


   int d = input/dimes;
   input -= d*dimes;
   String B = "Dimes:" +d;

   //output dimes
   System.out.println(B);


   int n = input/nickles;
   input -= n*nickles;
   String C = "Nickles:" +n;

   //output nickles
   System.out.println(C);


   int p = input/pennies;
   input -= p*pennies;
   String D = "Pennies:" +p;

   //output pennies
   System.out.println(D);




  } 







}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new coin().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Now I think what is needed is to ditch the scanner which plugs in user input to the console to do the work and somehow get the user input from the textbox in the gui but I have absolutely no idea how to make that happen

Also im a begginer so if you can make it easy to understand would be greatly appreciated, simple is best.

also found a tut that helped but have not been able to use that to try and make work what I want.

**Link to Tut**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33536/An-Introduction-to-Java-GUI-Programming

Comment: make use of getText(). use it in your actionPerformed()

Comment: I recommend to read oracle tutorials about swing before start using a gui editor if you don't understand, but basically gui is event base.. when you click the button `jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);` this method get execute, here you get the data entered!

Comment: Would I replace the scanner with getText()?

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans earned a reputation with me years ago for creating convoluted GUI code.  Never really tested it for myself, but this seems to be a lot of code for so simple an application.

When converting a console based app to a GUI based one, you must ask yourself this question:
How does the user interact with the system?

In your case, your console app interacted with the user by:

1. Outputting a prompt for input
2. Accepting input

Now, you must address how to change these two interactions to a GUI layout.  It should involve very minimal modification to your existing code, while adding GUI code to handle the input/output.

In your case, you have a label that acts as the prompt, a textarea that houses the input, and a button that acts as the acceptance of the input.

So the flow of your program is this:  User types into textarea -> User hits submit -> System accepts input and processes it -> System outputs change in terms of Quarters, Dimes, etc.

Now, we code it...

Step 1: Set up GUI mechanisms.  You have that down

Step 2: Process user input:  You do this in your handler for the Calculate button, which in your case appears to be jButton1ActionPerformed

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Initialize varriables
    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickles = 5;
    int pennies = 1;

    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //prompt user to enter an integer, not erroneous input
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //future code
}
```

Note how input has the same function as it did in your console app, we just get it by different means.  Since a GUI system is driven by user input, we should not loop continuously until the user enters valid input, we simply tell the user that their input is invalid, then let them input a valid number.  We check to see if the number is valid (input between 1 and 99) and do processing, otherwise do nothing (and prompt for valid input?)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Initialize varriables
    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickles = 5;
    int pennies = 1;

    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //prompt user to enter an integer, not erroneous input
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //if input in the range of [1, 99]
    if(1 <= input && input <= 99) {
        //do processing
    }
    else {
        //prompt user for valid input, for example by using JOptionPane
    }
}
```

Now: Output.  Instead of doing System.out.println on A, B, C, and D, you just need to set the text of your JComponents that represent quarter, dime, etc amounts.  At the moment you seem to be missing labels/textareas for your totals, so I'd add those first, then use setText(A), setText(B), etc for those.

Comment: Awesome I think I have got most of it, Do you know how I can pull varriables from another button? http://gyazo.com/fc62c0e8be51c00b29fd1fe0dfa8ce39

Comment: You mean variables declared in another method, such as quarters in jButton1ActionPerformed in another ActionPerformed?  Only way to do it  in your case is to declare the integers as global variables, so they are all accessible in the same level of encapsulation as your methods.    For example, jButton1 and jButton1ActionPerformed are on the same level.  So if you moved int quarters; to the same area jButton1 is defined, you could access it in any method in the class.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. Thank you kindly mu

Answer (score 0):

that is not a 100% solution I have spent a lil time tweaking it up for you so you find an exit

try this code

```
package test;


    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;

    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author Christ
     */
    public class coin extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public coin() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Enter a Number (1-99)");

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Quarters");

        jLabel3.setText("Dimes");

        jLabel4.setText("Nickles");

        jLabel5.setText("Pennies");

        jButton1.setText("Calculate");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Clear");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                         .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,        179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 53, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:


        // Initialize varriables
        int quarters = 25;
        int dimes = 10;
        int nickles = 5;
        int pennies = 1;

        //Loop starts here


        System.out.println("Enter in a number between 1-99");

        // Blank Output for spacing
        System.out.println();
        // User Input "remember this for reference"
        Scanner Userinput = new Scanner(System.in);


       int input = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());



       int q = input/quarters;
       input -= q*quarters;
       jLabel2.setText("Quarter: "+q);

        //Blank Output for spacing
        System.out.println();


       //output quarters


       int d = input/dimes;
       input -= d*dimes;
       jLabel3.setText("Dimes: "+d);

       //output dimes


       int n = input/nickles;
       input -= n*nickles;
       jLabel4.setText("Nickles: "+n);

       //output nickles


       int p = input/pennies;
       input -= p*pennies;
       jLabel5.setText("Pennies: "+q);

       //output pennies





    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(coin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new coin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration       


    }
```